# Convert least squares problem $\| ZXd - y\|^2$ into form $\|A\text{vec}(X) - b \|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I have a least squares problem in this form 
$$ \| ZXd - y \|^2 $$
where $X$ is rectangular matrix of my variables, $Z$ - rectangular matrix of constants, $d$ and $y$ just vectors.

And i want to convert this problem into more canonical form
$$\|A\text{vec}(X) - b \|^2$$

where $\text{vec}(X)$ stacks columns of matrix $X$ into one big vector

So my question is - how i can obtain new matrix of coefficients $A$ and vector $b$?

[This wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) provides some ideas of obtaining $A$ matrix but i still have not idea how to obtain vector $b$

PS Sorry for my English.

Comment: Yes Kronecker products is the way to go. $b$ will be the vectorization of $y$ since which it already is a vector will be itself, $A$ will be the composition of "Multiplication by $Z$ from left" and "Multiplication by $d$ from right".

Comment: So just $A = (d^T \otimes Z)vec(X)$ and $b = y$? Much easier than i thought, thank you!

Comment: Yes quite close, but the vec(X) is what you will solve for later. Take it once at a time $A = M_1M_2$ one $M$ is the from left by $Z$ and the other from the right by $d$ then determine them one by one.

Comment: Yes, it's my misprint. Can you write it as math.stackexchange answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can rewrite it with vectorization and Kronecker products:

$$\|{\bf ZXd - y}\|^2 \to \|{\bf M_1M_2}\text{vec}({\bf X}) - \text{vec}({\bf y})\|^2$$

where $$\cases{{\bf M_1} = \text{Multiplication from left by }{\bf Z}\\{\bf M_2} = \text{Multiplication from right by }{\bf d}}$$

Now let us construct these matrices

$$ {\bf AXB} \to ({\bf B}^T\otimes {\bf A})\text{vec}({\bf X})$$

Now for $\bf M_1$: $\cases{\bf A=Z\\\bf B=I} \to {\bf M_1} = ({\bf Z}^T\otimes {\bf I})$.

And for $\bf M_2$: $\cases{\bf A=I\\\bf B=d} \to {\bf M_2} = ({\bf I}^T\otimes {\bf d})$.

So our vectorized system becomes: $$\begin{align*}\min_{\text{vec}({\bf X})}&\|{\bf M_1 M_2 } \text{vec}({\bf X})-\text{vec}({\bf y})\|^2= \\\min_{\text{vec}({\bf X})}&\|\underset{\text{The }{\bf A}\text{ you are looking for}}{\underbrace{({\bf Z}^T\otimes {\bf I})({\bf I}^T\otimes {\bf d})}{ \text{vec}({\bf X})}}-\text{vec}({\bf y})\|^2\end{align*}$$